# How can I implement a simple long press gesture using SwiftUI on an Apple Watch?

Tags: swift, swiftui, apple-watch, watchos-6

I've been playing around a bit and while this code works in iOs it won't work on WatchOS

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .onTapGesture {
                print("tapped!")
        }
        .onLongPressGesture {
            print("Long pressed!")
        }
    }
}
```

When I say it "doesn't work" I mean doing the long press on an Apple Watch doesn't run the code within the closure block.

I'm thinking maybe `.onLongPressGesture` shouldn't be used with an Apple Watch, and there is some other method, but I can't figure out what it is (my understanding is force touch is being done away with in WatchOS 7.0).

---

edit: This is the actual code that's not working (it has a lot of methods attached to it, so it's hard to troubleshoot)

```swift
    var body: some View {
        Start()
            .background(NavigationLink(destination: RunSelector(), isActive: self.$showRunSelectorList) {EmptyView()})
            .background(NavigationLink(destination: RunningTimer(myIntervals: allIntervals.week1d1), isActive: self.$showRunningTimer) {EmptyView()})
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            .onTapGesture {
                self.showRunningTimer = true
        }
        .onLongPressGesture {
            print("Long pressed!")
            self.showRunSelectorList = true
        }
        .focusable(true)
        .digitalCrownRotation(self.$crownValue, from: 0.1, through: 5.0, sensitivity: .low, isContinuous: false, isHapticFeedbackEnabled: true)
        .onAppear() {
            HealthKitSetupAssistant.authorizeHealthKit { (authorized, error) in
                guard authorized else {
                    let baseMessage = "HealthKit Authorization Failed"
                    if let error = error {
                        print("\(baseMessage). Reason: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    } else {
                        print(baseMessage)
                    }
                    return
                }
                
                print("HealthKit Successfully Authorized.")
            }
        }.onReceive(Just(self.crownValue)) { output in
            if self.crownValue > 0.1 {
                self.showRunSelectorList = true
                self.crownValue = 0.0
            } else {
                print("The value is \(self.crownValue)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 12 / watchOS 7. You'd probably met Simulator bug when `print`  sometimes does not work. Just quit Simulator and relaunch watch app.

Comment: this worked, although I swore I tried it so many times after many simulator changes etc., but maybe I should show the actual code that it's not working on

Comment: Now I'm certain this problem persists because, although there /is/ a problem with printing to the console sometimes, I've added another method `            WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(WKHapticType.notification)` and it's still not working.